# How do I stretch a float left div horizontally in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I let a float: left div behave like it hasn't been set to "float: left"?

I want to let #content stretch horizontally til the end of the website, without setting a specific width. Exactly like the footer that can be seen here. `[https://jsfiddle.net/mcvcqzp0/1/]`

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mcvcqzp0/19/

```
---
```

Without using *width* property the only way I know is using flex. You need an extra *div* wrapping #newnavigator and #content.

Comment: EXACTLY! Thank you all for your help thats exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the element to 100%, so it will stick to the width of the parent element.
In your case:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/mcvcqzp0/1/1/
```

set

```
#newnavigator {
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I knew I forgot something, I was talking about the #content div

Answer (score 0):

Did you expect something like this?

```
 #content { display:block }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mcvcqzp0/13/

If not, I don't understand you. 
What I'm doing in fiddle, only change float:left to display:block

Comment: As u can see the #newnavigator is a navigator and the #content is where later on content is displayed, but for some reason the #content div isnt stretched out till the end of the window like the footer did and I want to fix that. 

A small example resize the result window in jsfiddle and u see the footers width changes dynamically while maintaining the margin and i want the same behaviour for #content

Comment: #content is stretching now like i want it to, but now the #newnavigator is in the #content and I want it outside paralel to #content. 

Im sorry im not very good in describing problems in english

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mcvcqzp0/20  .... I recommend you to change the structure,  because it's not good designed.